# Entity Framework Core - Filter By List Of Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm looking for a way to implement a SQL query with connected OR statements based on a list of filters in EF Core. In SQL it would simply look like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE (ColA = 'filterForA1' AND ColB = 'filterForB1') OR [...] OR (ColA = 'filterForAx' AND ColB = 'filterForBx')
```

So a naive approach to get a SQL query and executing it then by `FromSqlRaw` would be:

```cs
string sqlFilter = "";
bool first = true;
foreach (var filterSet in filterSets) {
  if (!first) { sqlFilter += "OR" } else { first = false; }

  sqlFilter += $"(ColA = '{filterSet.A}' AND ColB = '{filterSet.B}')";
}
```

But this would make the code vulnerable to injections, so I'm wondering if there is a better solution for handling a list of filters in EF Core?

Edit: A LINQ query would also be a very good solution. But I couldn't figure out how to do it with LINQ. So the SQL query from above is only the example what the result should look like.

Comment: Why SQL? Why do not use LINQ?

Comment: .Where(row => listOfFilters.Contains(row.a)) ?

Comment: or you use a loop. foreach (...) { query = query.Where(...) }